# Convert String/Unknown Format to Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, type-conversion

I need to convert this `OpenSSL::PKey::DH#compute_key` (`aString` type) to integer ([documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/PKey/DH.html#method-i-compute_key)). These are the tests I ran to check the format output by `compute_key`.

```
...
...
shared_key = dh1.compute_key(public_key)
puts "1"
puts shared_key
puts "2"
puts shared_key.to_s
puts "3"
puts shared_key.inspect
puts "4"
puts shared_key.to_yaml
```

These output:

```
1
���`���,�L@�9�������Q���?�J����
2
���`���,�L@�9�������Q���?�J����
3
"\xD2\xBD\xBA`\xBC\xB1\xA6\x11,\xE9L@\x8C9\xA9\xAF\x88\xFD\x8F\xD9\x92Q\xE9\x93\x92?\xBCJ\xFB\xD2\xAC\xEE"
4
--- !binary |-
  0r26YLyxphEs6UxAjDmpr4j9j9mSUemTkj+8SvvSrO4=
```

I'm expecting an integer value of

```
 95320918630576230557892713337132753026878147296634144208600768328265758846190
```

if formatted correctly. I'm guessing on converting the whole string/data outputted by `compute_key` to binary first, then into an integer. But I'm not too sure if that's the right approach. I also tried `String::unpack`, but it didn't give me the expected format (or perhaps my input parameters to `unpack` is not right). Please help.

Comment: What do you get with `shared_key.encoding`?

Comment: Thanks for the immediate reply. It gave me ASCII-8BIT :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I have managed to get the number, however I've no idea why it behaves this way:

Step 1. Get binary representation of the string:

```
shared_key.unpack('B*').first
```

Step 2. Convert this into integer:

```
shared_key.unpack('B*').first.to_i(2)

#=>  95320918630576230557892713337132753026878147296634144208600768328265758846190
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
shared_key.encode( "UTF-8", "binary", :invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace).unpack("B*").first.to_i(2)
```

Comment: I followed the example on internet
dh1 = OpenSSL::PKey::DH.new(2048)
der = dh1.public_key.to_der #you may send this publicly to the participating party
dh2 = OpenSSL::PKey::DH.new(der)
dh2.generate_key! #generate the per-session key pair
symm_key1 = dh1.compute_key(dh2.pub_key)
symm_key2 = dh2.compute_key(dh1.pub_key)
binary_data = symm_key1.encode( "UTF-8", "binary", :invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace).unpack("B*")
binary_data.first.to_i(2)

Comment: I got this answer 
1.9.2-p320 :032 > binary_data.first.to_i(2)
 => 9752200127189995346750183124313721331197437820338462335504712092318156938130760527582751965971075875231537622180265645686035158408729235976178146980466365923782272021236312187963244201731848743155782029843423804233023816573234418403517032381062......

Comment: @sawa please review my answer. It would be good to get guidance from you.

Comment: Ohh... My guess to convert it binary first seems right then :) Thank you for showing me this method. Works now thanks! :D